# How to properly use custom loss (e.g. dice coefficient) with tensorflow.keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss

I am trying to input a custom loss or metric function into tensorflow.keras model compile but am getting an error. It looks like the inputs are not being passed correctly.

I have been able to run model compile/fit with the following tensorflow losses:

```
loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError() # Breaks if I remove ()
loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits # Breaks if I add ()
```

I am confused by the difference in syntax which makes these work (maybe incorrectly?) and if I use a custom dice loss, it doesn't work with either syntax.

When I run the custom dice loss below, the input labels is passed correctly as `batch_size*height*width` but the input logits is passed as `None,None,None,None` (does not seem correct?) and the dice loss function errors out. I am looking to do batch optimization, so the loss should be calculated on each batch by the `model.fit`.

```
def generalized_dice(labels, logits):
    smooth = 1e-17
    shape = tf.TensorShape(logits.shape).as_list()
    depth = int(shape[-1])
    labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth, dtype=tf.float32)
    logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    weights = 1.0 / (tf.reduce_sum(labels, axis=[0, 1, 2])**2)

    numerator = tf.reduce_sum(labels * logits, axis=[0, 1, 2])
    numerator = tf.reduce_sum(weights * numerator)

    denominator = tf.reduce_sum(labels + logits, axis=[0, 1, 2])
    denominator = tf.reduce_sum(weights * denominator)

    loss = 2.0*(numerator + smooth)/(denominator + smooth)
    return loss


def generalized_dice_loss(dice):
    return 1-dice 


model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_x], outputs=[predictions])

loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError() # Breaks if I remove (), with inputs being passed as None's 
# loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits 
metric = generalized_dice # If no parantehses, labels passed as None's; 
# Both tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits and generalized_dice don't work if I add () saying inputs and labels must be provided; since I am training in batches, these need to be provided by the model during training, not when I am defining loss?  

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),  
              loss=loss, 
              metrics=[metric])
```

Due to the input to dice loss being passed as None's,

```
labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Results in:

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'indices' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: uint8, int32, int64
```